# How do I set up timeout for remote desktop users?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, terminal-server, windows-server-2000

In my job I usually have to connect to several different servers with remote desktop. However,  more often than not I will get the message "Terminal server has exceeded the maximum number of allowed connections", because my colleagues just closes the remote desktop window instead of logging out.

Usually I will call the admin and get him to release one of the idle sessions on the server but this method is getting real old, real fast. So I was wondering how I setup the server so that idle sessions will timeout after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Terminal Services Configuration -> Connections

Right click on RDP-Tcp, choose properties and select Sessions tab.

You will then see the options for ending disconnected or idle sessions after x minutes, hours or days.

Comment: +1 - That's how we had our servers setup so after 30 minutes of being disconnected it would logoff the session since I was the guy that had to kick people off.

Answer (score 4):

Also configurable through group policy, if you don't feel like touching all your servers' settings individually.

Comment: Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Sessions\

Comment: Thanks, Justin, for being not-lazy, which I have utterly failed to do today.  ;)